# Integral of sin(z) given the below condition

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Find 
$$\int_{\gamma} \sin(z) \, dz $$
where $\gamma$ is a circle of radius 5 centred at the point $i$.

My approach: since  $z(t) =5e^{it} + i $, I tried to integrate with respect to $t$ as below:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (5e^{it} + i)  \, dt $$

But I wasn't sure whether I am doing this correctly and would appreciate if someone clarify this.

Comment: The function $\sin$ is entire, so any integral along a closed path is $0$.

Comment: @ajotatxe FYI, I am not allowed to use entire function as my part of proof, and cannot just use Cauchy Integral theorm to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_\gamma\sin zdz=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(i+5e^{it})5i e^{5i t}dt$$

Can you finish?

Comment: What is this theorem called?

Comment: No theorem, this is the very definition of complex integration along a piecewise differentiable path.

Answer (score 1):

If $z(t) = 5 e^{it}+i$, $dz = 5 i e^{it}\; dt$ so
$$ \int_\gamma f(z)\; dz = \int_0^{2\pi} f(5 e^{it}+i)(5 i e^{it})\; dt $$ 
An antiderivative is $F(5 e^{it}+i)$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.